# How to divide a time range into periods in EXCEL (no VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I´m trying to code with EXCEL formulas (no VBA), a way to divide a time range into periods,
for example, given below arrival and departure

```
Arrival: 19/09/2023  05:00:00
Departure: 21/09/2023  18:00:00
```

It would separate as

```
Day 1
00h-04h - 0
04h-06h - 1
06h-22h - 16
22h-0h  - 2

Day 2
00h-04h - 4
04h-06h - 2
06h-22h - 16
22h-0h  - 2

Day 3
00h-04h - 4
04h-06h - 2
06h-22h - 12
22h-0h  - 0

Day 4
00h-04h - 0
04h-06h - 0
06h-22h - 0
22h-0h  - 0
```

Any tips on how to achieve this?
Many thanks for at least reading this ...

FranciscoRC